# Swap 2 div elements Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

So I want to swap two div elements that have a CKEditor inside. I viewed some of the previous questions and tried to do it that way. It's all OK, the elements are swapped. But one of the elements loses its content and becomes non-editable.

```
<div id="sections">    
    <div id="apresentacao_div">
            <label id="apresentacao_label" for="apresentacao">Apresentação</label>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </button>
            <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="apresentacao"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
    </div>
    <div id="intro_div">
            <label id="intro_label" for="intro">Introdução</label>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="remove(this)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="upDiv(this)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </button>
            <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="intro"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to swap the two divs within the div with the id = "sections". And this is my code to swap:

```
function upDiv(ex) {
  var div = document.getElementById("sections").getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (i = 0; i < div.length; i = i + 4) {
    if (div[i + 4].id.localeCompare(ex.parentNode.id) == 0) {
      swapElements(div[i + 4], div[i]);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function swapElements(obj1, obj2) {
  obj2.nextSibling === obj1 ? obj1.parentNode.insertBefore(obj2, obj1.nextSibling) : obj1.parentNode.insertBefore(obj2, obj1);
}
```

The for loop increments by 4 because of the transformation of the textarea into CKEditor adds a lot of new divs (4 in this case).
Can anyone help?

Comment: Questions like this being downvoted are the reason SO is getting so much hatred recently.  @StackJP has provided a perfect description of his problem, shown effort in resolving it and added additional comments to explain why some of his code may seem strange.  What's wrong here?

Comment: A couple of reasons he may have been downvoted. 1) Seems like he is using asp.net, but it was not tagged. 2) It is not clear if he wants to swap the divs with each other, or with some other elements. 3) I see no element `sections` in his markup.

Comment: I've made some corrections.

Comment: @StackJP so do you want to swap `intro` with `apresentacao`?

Comment: @HanletEscaño yes, thats what i want to do!

Answer (score 0):

Not having too much familiarity with exactly what you are doing but i would try using a 'clone' method and then removing the original element off the page. It may be the values are not being copied, only the outline is but a clone should mean it duplicates as it is on the page and not how it is from the page source.

Answer (score 0):

What about just swapping the data instead? Moving the DOM elements around is causing problems to me as well, but this works:

Replace your upDiv with this:

```
function upDiv()
{
    var introData = CKEDITOR.instances['intro'].getData();
    var presentacaoData = CKEDITOR.instances['apresentacao'].getData();
    CKEDITOR.instances['intro'].setData(presentacaoData);
    CKEDITOR.instances['apresentacao'].setData(introData);
    return false;
}
```

This takes the data from one, and puts it in the other and vice versa.

Also, I noticed your controls don't have the `runat` server attribute set. You may want to change this:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl runat="server" ID="intro"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Finally, you call the function from your button like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="return upDiv();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
</button>
```